# Bluetooth hc-06 и android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Есть одна очень серьезная проблема. Мое приложение должно узнавать, когда разорвано соединение(пока что только из-за того, что юзер вырубил bluetooth).

Я сделал таким образом:

Это отдельный поток (чтобы каждые 5 секунд проверять работает ли блютус).

```
 @Override
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        try {
            newCheck = new BluetoothCheck(bluetooth);
            if (!newCheck.isBluetoothEnabled()) textView.setText("Отсутствует подключение...");
            else textView.setText("Подключение установлено");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

А вот здесь инициализируется нужный модуль (в моем случае hc-06) и запускает нужный мне поток.

```
public void tryConnectToWatch() {
    if (bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
        try {

            BluetoothDevice device = bluetooth.getRemoteDevice("20:16:08:16:14:57");
            Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});
            clientSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
            clientSocket.connect();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Браслет подключен успешно.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Thread thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
            }
         }
     }
```

Синтаксических ошибок нет, но также ничего не происходит. Мне один раз ставит - подключение установлено и все, дальше каждые 5 секунд проверка не идет.

Класс BluetoothCheck писал сам и да я знаю что он не нужен, я его создал после прошлой попытки. Вот код:

```
class BluetoothCheck{

BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

public BluetoothCheck(BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter) {
    this.bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothAdapter;
}


public boolean isBluetoothEnabled() {
    if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {return false;}
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работал с блютуз модулем HC-06, подключенным к Arduino, при этом использовал публичный метод `createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord`. Полученный `BluetoothSocket` корректно выкидывал `IOException` в случае выключения блютуз модуля.

В качестве примера ниже часть кода сервиса под работе с блютуз, написанного на Kotlin'е. Разобрать происходящее несложно, если не обращать внимания на вопросительные и восклицательные знаки (блок `use` -- это аналог try-with-resources).

После подключения запускаем поток `btEventThread`, который постоянно пытается что-то прочитать из сокета блокирующим вызовом `reader.readLine()`, после чего обрабатываем полученные данные как угодно. В случае разрыва соединения (в том числе, при выключении блютуз модуля телефона или Arduino) просто обрабатываем `IOException`.

Бонус: для передачи полученных из сокета данных для дальнейшей обработки, а также для нотификации состояния сервиса использовал [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

```
class BtService : Service() {

    private val sppUuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private var bluetoothSocket: BluetoothSocket? = null;

    fun connect(deviceAddress: String) {
        val device = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress)
        if (bluetoothSocket == null || !bluetoothSocket!!.isConnected) {
            bluetoothSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(sppUuid)
            try {
                if (!bluetoothSocket!!.isConnected) {
                    bluetoothSocket!!.connect()
                }
                btEventThread.start()
                //TODO: Notify socket connected
            } catch(e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                //TODO: Report error
            }
        } else {
            //TODO: Notify already connected
        }
    }

    private val btEventThread = object: Thread() {
        override fun run() {
            if (bluetoothSocket != null) {
                try {
                    bluetoothSocket!!.inputStream.bufferedReader().use { reader ->
                        while (!isInterrupted) {
                            val message = reader.readLine()
                            //TODO: Do something with it
                        }
                    }
                } catch(e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    stopSelf()
                    //TODO: Notify that server has stopped
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        btEventThread.interrupt()
        bluetoothSocket?.close()
    }
}
```